# How to check if an email address matches with a password

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm currently created an application that sends an eMail using the JavaMail API.  The problem is, if I want the user to enter a certain password that matches with their eMail address and have them send an eMail, it'll create an error and the eMail won't send.

I've absolutely no idea where to go with this or if it's even possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to send the email as the user, or email the password to the user?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm trying to send the email as a user.

Comment: Then you'd also need to know the user's email server.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you explain to me with further detail with an answer?  I can get the user's email server, but what do I do with that?

Comment: You didn't post your JavaMail code, but basically; Where you set the server, change it to the user's. Where you set your email and password, change it to the user's. Then send the email.

Comment: If you look at the information that various email clients like Thunderbird ask for to set up a new account, that's what you'll need to ask for.  In general, you can't (for example) assume that the user's email address is in any way related to the user's email server name or the name of the account the user uses to login to that server.