# Sending emails with different hosts using JavaMail

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-mail

I'm creating an application that is used to send emails through a Java program.  The code I currently have checks if the email and password is valid.  The problem with this is that i'm using the **smtp.live.com** host to send messages, if the user were to enter something other than example@live.com, it wouldn't work.

Here's my current code that authenticates the user's email and password:

```
 import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Authenticator {

    static Data d = new Data();

    public static void authenticate() throws MessagingException {

        d.password = LoginWindow.passwordField.getText();
        d.username = LoginWindow.usernameField.getText();

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.live.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");


        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        try {
            Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
            try {
                trans.connect("smtp.live.com", 587, d.username, d.password);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Working, great!");
            } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password or Email Incorrect!");
            }
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something that I can do so that all domains will work instead of just the live.com domain?

Comment: You can use an SMTP service that allows that. There isn't anything you can do about it in your code, this is enforced by the server.

Comment: @pvg Do you know any services that allow that?

Comment: Sendgrid, AWS, lots of others. Usually costs something, except for very low volumes and requires some amount of setup to ensure you're not a spammer.

Comment: As I described in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112749/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-matches-with-a-password), there's lots of other information you need to ask for other than just username and password if you want to be able to send email using the user's mail server and account.

Comment: @BillShannon Is there a method for getting the user's mailing server?  Or do I have to figure out how to do this on my own?

Comment: The simple way is to just ask the user.  The more complicated way is to create a "table" that maps from common email addresses to the corresponding server names, and then ask the user for the cases not handled by the table.  For example, if the address is @gmail.com, you can know what the mail server name is for Gmail.  Thunderbird already has a facility to do this, with a bunch of xml files with information about popular mail servers.  You can look into that if you don't want to reinvent it yourself.  But anything other than just asking the user is **a lot** more work.